# Как используя только datetime добавить к текущей дате произвольное количество месяцев?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Как к текущей дате добавить произвольное кол-во месяцев **без сторонних библиотек, кроме datetime**? Проблема в том, что нужно учитывать сколько дней в месяце (31 или 30) и так далее.

Comment: К 31 января добавляем 1 месяц - какой результат ожидается?

Comment: @andreymal: 28/29 февраля.

Answer (score 3):

[Точно такой же вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4130922/5308802) задавали много лет назад на enSO, но идеального ответа так и не нашли. Дело в том, что хотя в Питоне имеется удобный класс **`timedelta`**, который позволяет прибавлять/отнимать значения от дат, он работает максимум с днями.

Если бы Вам не нужно было учитывать количество дней в месяце, я бы посоветовал использовать его с 30-днями. В противном случае остаётся либо использовать дополнительные библиотеки, либо писать свой код:

```
import datetime, calendar

def add_months(sourcedate, months):
    month = sourcedate.month - 1 + months
    year = sourcedate.year + month // 12
    month = month % 12 + 1
    day = min(sourcedate.day, calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1])
    return datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

<sub>P.S.1: [Оригинальный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4131114/5308802) от [@DaveWebb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3171/dave-webb).</sub>
<sub>P.S.2: Надеюсь, ***calendar*** не подподает под ограничение, ведь эта библиотека стандартна для Питона, а также позволяет абсолютно точно учитывать длины месяцев.</sub>

Пример работы:

```
x = datetime.datetime.now()
# datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 11, 14, 50, 25, 896430)

add_months(x, 25)
# datetime.date(2020, 5, 11)

add_months(x, -2)
# datetime.date(2018, 2, 11)
```

Comment: тестирование показывает, что результат совпадает с `sourcedate + relativedelta(months=months)` только быстрее работает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать `timedelta`:

```
import datetime as DT

now = DT.datetime.now()
print(now)  # 2018-04-11 16:43:07.103997

now_2 = now + DT.timedelta(days=30 * 2)
print(now_2)  # 2018-06-10 16:43:07.103997
```